# Using static_assert to verify bitfields in a typedef union of a struct and an uint32_t

Tags: c++, typedef, unions, bit-fields, static-assert

I am trying to use static_assert for registers for a FPGA and defined the following unions of struct with bitfields and all variable. But whenever I try to compile static_assert won't compile and I get an error saying the variable doesn't name a type. If I try to forward declare, it doesn't solve the problem. I'm not sure what the right pattern is to get the static_assert to work. Any ideas of the correct way to write the following code?

so.h:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define t_f2bits_addr (0x0000)

typedef union {
    struct {
        uint32_t do_it : 1;
        uint32_t fault : 1;
    } field;
    uint32_t all;
} t_f2bits_type;
#define t_f2bits_ptr (*(volatile t_f2bits_type *)t_f2bits_addr)

t_f2bits_type myVar; 
myVar.field.do_it = 0x1;
myVar.field.fault = 0x1;
static_assert(myVar.all == 0x3, "Not equal");
```

so.c

```
#include "so.h"

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

run:

```
g++ so.c
In file included from so.c:1:0:
so.h:15:1: error: ‘myVar’ does not name a type
 myVar.field.do_it = 0x1;
 ^~~~~
so.h:16:1: error: ‘myVar’ does not name a type
 myVar.field.fault = 0x1;
 ^~~~~
so.h:17:1: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
 static_assert(myVar.all == 0x3, "Not equal");
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
so.h:17:1: error: the value of ‘myVar’ is not usable in a constant expression
so.h:14:15: note: ‘myVar’ was not declared ‘constexpr’
 t_f2bits_type myVar;
               ^~~~~
```

Comment: Do note that your code is illegal in C++.  C++ doesn't allow type punning through a union unless it is to access the common initial sequence of members that are shared by standard layout classes inside the union.

Comment: You cannot write code at global scope.  Put it in a function (or in `main`).  You will then find that you cannot use `static_assert` in this way.  It only performs compile-time checks.  Plus what @NathanOliver said.

Comment: Despite the fact that type-punning through union is illegal in C/C++, everyone does this :)

Comment: Was definitely not my intention to subvert the C++ language haha... but then is there a pattern where I can use assert (preferably static_assert) to test the functionality of the bitfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++20, you might use [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast):

```
struct field {
    uint32_t do_it : 1;
    uint32_t fault : 1;
};
constexpr field myVar = [](){
    field myVar;
    myVar.do_it = 0x1;
    myVar.fault = 0x1;
    return myVar;
}();
static_assert(std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(myVar) == 0x3, "Not equal");
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/96WW5b34Y) (only msvc has `std::bit_cast` there).

Notice that bitfield is really implementation specific (think about endianess), and the `static_assert` might pass or not depending of compilers/architecture/...

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas of the correct way to write the following code?

There is no correct way. It's not possible to use `static_assert` to check if bitfields are in specific places.

You are using C++. Do not use an union. Write a normal class with accessors that access specific bits with masks - such way is clear, portable and guaranteed to work. Alternatively use a `std::bitset`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use bit fields, use old fashioned bit masks

```
namespace FpgaRegister
{
    constexpr uint32_t do_it = 1 << 0;
    constexpr uint32_t fault = 1 << 1;

    constexpr uint32_t all = do_it | fault;
}

static_assert(FpgaRegister::all == 0x3, "Not equal");
```

Comment: bit fields is a requirement that cannot be removed

Comment: why not to change requirements then ? Binding to implementation defined features is a wrong approach to a problem to begin with.

Comment: I didn't mean to use it so loosely but its a requirement of the question.